# Wordpress- Two forms in contact us page

Tags: wordpress, contact-form, multiple-forms

I have two forms in wordpress contact us page. 
One form use simple `mail()` and the other uses `mail()` with attachment. 
I have to process these forms in a single page.
I'm using `inner.php` (wordpress) to process forms. 
I can process multiple forms from different pages, but I'm unable to process forms from the same page. How can I do this.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: @swapnesh: Sorry.. I can't use ajax for this, b'coz it'll affect other functions in my wordpress site :(

Comment: you need to write a lot php code then if you want to keep it in a single page..what answer submitted below is ok at first glance by it is still taking you to another page(sendmail/join) and then from that page you need to redirected back to VALIDATE various conditions like - FORM 1 filled or not IF yes do blah blah IF not Blah blah..just take care of various conditions and flaws

Comment: @swapnesh: Below answer worked for me. Thank you for your precious time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that the way most people treat multiple forms on one page is to have each form post to another PHP file where the form is validated, its information is entered into a database or an email is sent off. So you usually have something like this:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="sendmail.php">
blah blah blah
</form>

<form name="mailinglist" method="post" action="join.php">
blah blah blah
</form>
```

That work great, but why would you create all those extra files when you can just have the form post to the same file and create multiple functions to process your multiple forms.
The solution is very simple and super efficient. 
First, lets create some forms.

```
<form name="mailinglist" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit" name="mailing-submit" value="Join Our Mailing List" />
</form>

<form name="contactus" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="text" name="subjet" />
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="contact-submit" value="Send Email" />
</form>
```

Now lets put some PHP code before the  tag to have different processes for each form.

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['mailing-submit'])) {
   //do something here;
}

if (!empty($_POST['contact-submit'])) {
   //do something here;
}
?>
```

Now all you need to do is create your processes within those two “if” statements and each form will be dealt with accordingly when it it filled and submitted.

[This](http://bavotasan.com/2009/processing-multiple-forms-on-one-page-with-php/) will help you.